# Dynamically changing a style in Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I'm writing a proof of concept Polymer 2.0 web component where I want to change the colour of a piece of text depending on the user input.

I've tried using Polymer 2.0's this.updateStyles({...}) and Polymer.updateStyles({...}) but neither is updating the text which is output.

e.g.

```
Polymer.updateStyles({'--tool-colour': 'green'});
```

I've written a plunker which demonstrates the problem [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/CMb7jj/).

I'm probably missing something simple, can someone help me out?

Comment: If you open the console on your plunker you'll see several 404 errors for shadycss components. I'd guess that has something to do with it.

Comment: Good spot. It could be that I'm getting the issue because I've just added to the basic Plunker example found on the Polymer website. I'll have to try this example out in a local environment where bower will hopefully ensure that dependencies get loaded (which doesn't look like is happening in Plunker as you've pointed out). I'll update this answer once I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jordan Running commented, the problem was due to missing dependencies. I'd written code in an online editor (Plunker) assuming that all I needed to get polymer working was a reference to 'webcomponents-loader.js' and links to the other web components my bespoke component was using (doh!).

To get my Polymer element working I used the [Polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/create-element-polymer-cli) facility provided by the Polymer team (specifically I used [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/create-element-polymer-cli) for creating a Polymer element template project).

When I then used:

```
polymer serve
```

To run a local webserver to "[serve](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli-commands#serve)" the app which was using my Polymer element, the dependencies then got resolved properly and the element worked.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this myself:

```
<template>
    <style>
        .green-icon {
            color: var(--green-color);
        }
        .red-icon {
            color: var(--red-color);
        }
    </style>
    <my-element class$="[[computeIconColor(boolProp)]]"></my-element>
</template>
```

then in the script:

```
computeIconColor(boolProp) {
    if (!!boolProp) return 'green-icon';
    return 'red-icon';
}
```

Comment: This example is using the Polymer 1.0 framework, not 2.0.

Comment: How is this not Polymer 2.0?

Comment: My mistake codeMonkey, using the dollar syntax is valid in Polymer 2. Whilst this works I still wanted to get the updateStyles method working.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is as Jordan Running stated that your webcomponentsjs is not loading.

The real thing is that you can't use `updateStyles` without webcomponentsjs which is rather unfortunate as there are situations where you probably won't need it at all.

In this case you could do
`this.setAttribute('style', '--tool-colour: red');`
but then again this won't work in browsers needing webcomponentsjs.

what I ended up doing create an behavior that either uses setAttributes (with merging for styles) or updateStyles depending on what is available. It code looks like this.

```
if (!window.ShadyCSS || (window.ShadyCSS && window.ShadyCSS.nativeCss === true)) {
    var newStyleString = '';
    for (var key in newStyle) {
        if (newStyle.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newStyleString += key + ': ' + newStyle[key] + ';';
        }
    }
    this.setAttribute('style', newStyleString);
} else {
    ShadyCSS.styleSubtree(this, newStyle);
}
```

So for usage I just write `this.updateStyles({'--tool-colour': 'green'});` as my behavior overwrites `updateStyles`.

The full code you can find here
https://github.com/daKmoR/grain-update-inline-style-behavior.
It's a little more as it also adds support for inline styles on IE11.

Comment: Whilst this works, I wanted to use the Polymer 2.0 library verbatim, without having to use a trick such as using setAttribute. This is still a neat approach though so +1.